# Is it illegal to post an "owner is armed" sign in Canada?

Tags: canada

I've been watching a [TV show](https://youtu.be/_JwryAnEeZw) about border security in Canada and in the episode a border officer mentions that posting an "owner is armed" sign inside your vehicle is illegal. Is this true and if so, what law is being violated in this case?

Comment: Your first sentence seems to be incomplete - "posting the sign inside your vehicle" is what?  Illegal?  The officer never says that.  She says "don't put that sign in your window while you're in Canada" but that could be construed as just safety advice.

Comment: Which would be logical, because a police officer stopping the car and noticing this sign might be more trigger happy.

Comment: You've been breaking copyright though with the YouTube video......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the appropriate snippet is about 10:59 and 11;35, and no one accused him of violating any law - they were just "playing it up" for the TV.  In fact if anything the opposite, as they did not confiscate the sign.

At 11:45 the officer explains her rationale  - effectively a sign like that could put an officer of the law on high alert as its outside the country norms - increasing the risk of the encounter for all involved.

I am not familiar with Canadian law per-se, but, like pretty much all jurisdictions, if one looks hard enough one can always find a law which can be stretched to justify the accusation of a crime.  Intimidation?  Threat of assault? - again though, he was not accused of any crime - and almost certainly this was just "done for TV", like the rest of these shows.